# 500 Error When Trying to Scrape ASP.NET Page in Python

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a python script to scrape my employer's online electronic schedule portal written in ASP.NET and present the data as a proper calendar feed. My progress so far can be seen at https://github.com/Renkin42/sws-scraper/blob/main/scraper.py . I have successfully logged in and retrieved the event data for the current week. However to get next week's data (arguably more useful) requires a second POST request to change from "Current Week" to "Specific Date" and set that date to Sunday of next week. Viewing this POST in my browser the response is a partial html tree of type "XHR", which seems to contain the data I'm after. However replicating the POST in my script I get the following response: `179|error|500|The page is performing an async postback but the ScriptManager.SupportsPartialRendering property is set to false. Ensure that the property is set to true during an async postback.|` . I can only imagine this is something being handled on the javascript side, as I don't see anything about this in the POST payload. Any suggestions on how I might proceed from here? I've seen mention of Selenium, but since it basically runs a browser in the background, I'm not sure if it can be used on a headless server without X.

I've checked that my script matches the POST as seen in my browser dev tools, including empty parameters. Program currently returns 500 error instead of expected partial html tree. Unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Best guess is page is using partial  post backs (ajax update panel to only update parts of the web page,  and thus not a full post back is occurring).  And .net of course has c# code server side,  and thus if that code behind doesn't have the correct values in code behind,  such code will not work.  And you can't see nor touch that server side code from the client side. Since this is their portal then why not hit the database in place of web scraping which is a very hacking approach to software

Comment: Sadly I am not an IT worker or anything and thus have no access to the database or server side code, hence why I’m even trying to scrape to begin with. This is indeed a hack I’m trying to run from my homelab to make my life easier because the existing system, to my knowledge, does not expose a CalDAV feed or public API.

Comment: Maybe the database exists on some server  and thus no api or any kind of interface is required at all. So you would query against the database and not the web site,  and that bypasses any need for a api or web scraping. In other words find out where the database data resides

Comment: I feel I haven’t been clear enough here. I am a lowly grocery store worker. I have zero access to Safeway’s internal systems and considering my data is on it I sincerely hope this database is not exposed to the public internet.

Comment: Much assumed this is your data on your company network. Given not this case, then you quite much now in a spot where you trying to take some data that you really don't have the correct tools and rights to do so.  Such data is not assumed to be public facing, but your job to use that data is different matter. Web scraping some static content page is easy, but pages with code behind that fires due to hitting a button is more challenging since no static URL exists for such data and the page is driven by a database and code behind.  This means you have to load the page and click that button.

Comment: In other words, code starts out with the first page, and on the server all kinds of variables are setup for the code to run, and THEN you change the date value, and press a button. That post back does NOT contain the information you need, but on the server the variables and code behind does. In other words, unlikely a entry point for the next week or set of data. You have to load first page and then click on that button. So, yes, you likely need something like selimum since  your software has to HOLD a copy of the browser in memory, click on the correct button, and THEN you scrape data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The final argument of my POST request was `”__ASYNCPOST”:”true”`, which I copied from the request in my browser. Changing it to `“false”` got rid of the error and returned the full html response rather than a partial one.